# Initialize boxed slice without clone or copy

Tags: rust

I'm trying to initialize a boxed slice of `None` values, such that the underlying type `T` does not need to implement `Clone` or `Copy`. Here a few ideal solutions:

```
fn by_vec<T>() -> Box<[Option<T>]> {
    vec![None; 5].into_boxed_slice()
}

fn by_arr<T>() -> Box<[Option<T>]> {
    Box::new([None; 5])
}
```

Unfortunately, the `by_vec` implementation requires `T: Clone` and the `by_arr` implemenation requires `T: Copy`. I've experimented with a few more approaches:

```
fn by_vec2<T>() -> Box<[Option<T>]> {
    let v = &mut Vec::with_capacity(5);
    for i in 0..v.len() {
        v[i] = None;
    }
    v.into_boxed_slice() // Doesn't work: cannot move out of borrowed content
}

fn by_iter<T>() -> Box<[Option<T>]> {
     (0..5).map(|_| None).collect::<Vec<Option<T>>>().into_boxed_slice()
}
```

`by_vec2` doesn't get past the compiler (I'm not sure I understand why), but `by_iter` does. I'm concerned about the performance of `collect` -- will it need to resize the vector it is collecting into as it iterates, or can it allocate the correct sized vector to begin with?

Maybe I'm going about this all wrong -- I'm very new to Rust, so any tips would be appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's start with `by_vec2`. You are taking a `&mut` reference to a `Vec`. You shouldn't do that, work directly with the `Vec` and make the `v` binding mutable.

Then you are iterating over the length of a `Vec` with a capacity of 5 and a length of 0. That means your loop never gets executed. What you wanted was to iterate over `0..v.cap()`.

Since your `v` is still of length 0, accessing `v[i]` in the loop will panic at runtime. What you actually want is `v.push(None)`. This would normally cause reallocations, but in your case you already allocated with `Vec::with_capacity`, so pushing 5 times will not allocate.

This time around we did not take a reference to the `Vec` so `into_boxed_slice` will actually work.

```
fn by_vec2<T>() -> Box<[Option<T>]> {
    let mut v = Vec::with_capacity(5);
    for _ in 0..v.capacity() {
        v.push(None);
    }
    v.into_boxed_slice()
}
```

Your `by_iter` function actually only allocates once. The Range iterator created by `0..5` knows that is exactly 5 elements long. So `collect` will in fact check that length and allocate only once.

Comment: I think the most important thing here is *the Range iterator [...] knows that is exactly 5 elements long*. That's how I'd write this code, although I'd use type inference on the `collect` type parameter: `(0..5).map(|_| None).collect::<Vec<_>>().into_boxed_slice()`.

Comment: Today you can actually collecy into a boxed slice dierectly. No need to go through vec.