# How can I copy a shared slice to have a boxed slice?

Tags: rust

I have a container:

```rust
pub struct Foo<T> {
    pub data: Box<[T]>,
}
```

I would like a method to initialize a new one from an existing slice:

```rust
impl<T> Foo<T> {
    fn from_slice(slice: &[T]) -> Foo<T> {
        Foo {
            data: Box::new(/* something here */),
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to create a `Foo` instance from any kind of slice, coming from a dynamic vector or a static string.

I suppose there is a reason why `vec!` is a macro, but is there a way to avoid writing one? I guess I could do `slice.to_vec().into_boxed_slice()`, but it doesn't seem right to create a `Vec` as a proxy to a clone...

I'm not using a `Vec` in my struct because the `data` isn't supposed to change in size during the lifetime of my container. It didn't feel right to use a `Vec` but I may be wrong.

Comment: I really don't understand please always share your goal of doing thing. Why not just `pub data: Vec<T>` ?

Comment: The data attribute isn't supposed to grow or shrink during the lifetime of my container, so it just didn't feel right.

Comment: To prevent changing the size you shouldn't make the field public. You can implement `IndexMut` if you want to allow to change values.

Comment: Thanks ! It's more that I didn't want any overhead... In C++ I wouldn't use an `std::vector` when a simpler type does the job. Bad habits from a poor background I guess. ;)

Comment: The array class you're referring to is statically sized, which doesn't fit every cases either. As for raw pointers... they are the only options you have in many situations where 1) you want the softer syntax of C++ over C and 2) can't afford using the STL and/or dynamic allocations for every bit of code you write. But thanks for the condescending tone, it's always appreciated.

I'll have a look at ndarray's implementation as a reference for my toy program, thanks.

Comment: (Comment above was intended to @Stargateur, who deleted his)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your slice contains `Copy` types, you can use `From` / `Into` to perform the construction:

```
pub struct Foo<T> {
    pub data: Box<[T]>,
}

impl<T> Foo<T> {
    fn from_slice(slice: &[T]) -> Foo<T>
    where
        T: Copy,
    {
        Foo { data: slice.into() }
    }
}
```

If your data is `Clone`, then you can use `to_vec` + `into_boxed_slice`:

```
impl<T> Foo<T> {
    fn from_slice(slice: &[T]) -> Foo<T>
    where
        T: Clone,
    {
        Foo { data: slice.to_vec().into_boxed_slice() }
    }
}
```

> it doesn't seem right to create a `Vec` as a proxy to a clone

You *aren't* cloning here. When you clone a type `T`, you get a type `T` back. You are starting with a `&[T]` and want to get a `Box<[T]>`, not a `[T]` (which you can't have).

Creating a boxed slice through a `Vec` means that you temporarily take up 3 machine-sized integers instead of 2; this is unlikely to be a performance problem compared to the amount of allocation performed.

I do agree with [starblue's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56373713/155423) that keeping a `Vec<T>` is probably simpler for most cases, but I admit that there are times where it's useful to have a boxed slice.

See also:

- [Initialize boxed slice without clone or copy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34284191/155423)
- [What is the use of into_boxed_slice() methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39615666/155423)
- [Performance comparison of a Vec and a boxed slice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33704592/155423)

> I suppose there is a reason why `vec!` is a macro

The [implementation of `vec!`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.35.0/src/liballoc/macros.rs#L38-L46) is public:

```
macro_rules! vec {
    ($elem:expr; $n:expr) => (
        $crate::vec::from_elem($elem, $n)
    );
    ($($x:expr),*) => (
        <[_]>::into_vec(box [$($x),*])
    );
    ($($x:expr,)*) => (vec![$($x),*])
}
```

It's really only a macro for syntax convenience (and because it uses the unstable `box` keyword); it takes the arguments, creates an array, boxes it, coerces it to a boxed slice, then converts it to a `Vec`.